# How Long To Re-Index External Id Field?

Tags: metadata, externalid

I have a `Custom Object` in salesforce which has 50k+ records with one of the field as external id. I accidentally unchecked `External Id` and saved it. Now when I recheck `External Id` and save, it says updating records and is running for a long time(more than 2 hours).

What shall I do now?

Comment: About all you can do is leave it as it needs to redo the index.

Comment: And now you wait.

Comment: 'wait' is the only option!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's nothing to do but wait for this long running operation to complete. (and hopefully learn from the experience!)